# What did that man say at the end of this video?

Tags: listening

Ok, see this short [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NGfh6Lh8o28&feature=youtu.be).

I couldn't understand what he said since **1:00**.

"I am gonna make dinner..."

**what else did he say after "*I am gonna make dinner...*"?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I really want a salad
>   A salad, I'm gonna put a whole bunch vegetables inside
>   I'm gonna get some red lettuce
>   Grab some carrots too
>   Brussel sprouts, my favourite
>   I like it, I like hot food, I like it spicy
>   I'm gonna put some radishes in too